# Rotate Icon o'clock of table row

Tags: jquery, css

Cannot seem to figure out why I cannot rotate an icon 180 degrees (like the other ones on the page) when clicking on the table row.

Clicking expand all/collapse all in table head should rotate adjacent chevron icon 180 degrees like the individual rows do. BUt it does not *sigh*

Any thoughts appreciated.

[test page here](https://builderincubator.cloudaccess.net/homebuilder-software-table#)

Comment: Please post your code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `$(this).parent().find(".rotator").addClass("upsidedown")` on ExpandAll click and remove the class on CollapseAll click using `$(this).parent().find(".rotator").removeClass("upsidedown")`

Answer (score 0):

in your `collapseall` and `expandall` click handlers, add and remove an `.upsidedown` class that will `rotate(180deg)`

Comment: I tried to no avail:

[code]<!--  Tables script  -->
<script>
   jQuery('table').on('click', 'tr.parent ', function(){
  jQuery(this).closest('tbody').toggleClass('open');
  });

jQuery(".expandall").click(function () {
  jQuery(this).hide();
  jQuery(".collapseall").show();
  jQuery("tbody").addClass('open');
jQuery(". rotator").addClass('upsidedown');
});
jQuery(".collapseall").click(function () {
  jQuery(this).hide();
  jQuery(".expandall").show();
  jQuery("tbody").removeClass('open');
jQuery(". rotator").addClass('upsidedown');
});
</script>[/code]

Comment: .upsidedown {  transform: rotate(180deg);}